# Reset the element after the jquery dialog closes

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, reset

I have a div element which is shown in my page. On a button click I make it a dialog. On closing the dialog disappears. I want the div to be reset as it was before the dialog was opened.
One way I can think to do this is I manually find all the styles, elements and attributes that were added when dialog was created and remove them on the closing of the dialog and reset my div to the page as it was before the dialog.

This solution looks a bit messy because any one can miss some style or elements that added to the dialog, and possibly is not the right way to do this.

Is there a better way to do this or I have to stick with this solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I’d just use a wrapper element for the dialog, so that jQuery will only touch the styles of that element, and leaves the child element alone.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin's 'destroy' method removes the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element **back to its pre-init state**.

```
$( "#yourdiv" ).dialog( "destroy" );
```

Comment: @Digvijay, have you tried the approach suggested in this answer?